# Creating a database in Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, environment-variables

Forgive me if this is a silly question, just been scratching my head for hours on this and cannot find a decent answer!

I'm writing a script to install a Laravel CMS to a database and would like to have it create the database from the given name if it does not exist.

I am at the stage where the system understands that the database does not exist and so needs to create it, But every time I run my code I get the exception:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'mytesting' (SQL: CREATE DATABASE mytesting)
```

I'm running the code as follows to initiate the database creation:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('CREATE DATABASE '.$_POST['DbDatabase']));
```

Now, I can understand that this may be crashing because the database name set in the .env is that of a database that is yet to exist, but I am wondering if there is a way to have the system simply auth to MySQL via login (No db name specified) and then create the table?

I've run the provided sql inside Sequel pro and it works there so I know it's valid, But am confused all the same!

If any yall could shine some light on this I'd be eternally grateful!

Thanks guys <3

Comment: Where are you running the create table statement?

Comment: Hi Ross! I'm running it in a controller via an AJAX Post request. Cheers

Comment: So, you are "writing a script" to install a Laravel CMS. I wonder, will this script be run within a Laravel application itself? You say you are running via an AJAX POSt. I wonder why exactly. One thing to consider is that usually, DB modifications in a Framework like Laravel, happen through what is known as **migrations**. So, I'm wondering if doing this via migrations could be a better idea.

Comment: Is this to create multiple databases on the fly or is it a one-off command that you would run just to install the cms?

Comment: Could you supply us with your .env file and perhaps your database config file also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out a way around this!

So instead of using Laravel's DB manager I ended up using a PDO instance instead as I could control what it did at a much more granular level. I specified the connection details out of the env file.

Thanks so much for your help guys <3